# Angular UI-Grid filter - After filtering page update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ui-grid

There is a UI-Grid filters are, if you refresh the page, how to stay out of the screening criteria?

Comment: try clearAllFilters(refreshRows, clearConditions, clearFlags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain the data with using [**$localstorage**](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Sample **key code**

```
PageLoad()
{
if(localStorage.get("GridData")!=undefined)
{
GridLoad(GridData)
}
}

GridLoad(GridData)
{
griview.data=GridData;// this is sample only 
localStorage.set("GridData",GridData)
}
```

Comment: is your answer relevant to the question? Think before posting an answer please.